# Having multiple clients connecting to Java Server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm creating a simple socket server using Java. I am able to connect one client at a time, I tried to implement Threads to handle multiple client. In my Server constructor I created a thread that handles the ServerSocket, and should keep listening for new clients. Once a socket is connected then I tried to create another thread to handle the client Socket. But I am still not able to connect more than one client. The second client I try to connect will not get IO streams.

```
public class Server extends JFrame {

private JTextField enterField;
private JTextArea displayArea;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;
private int counter = 1;

public Server() {
    super("Server");
    enterField = new JTextField();
    enterField.setEditable(false);
    enterField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            sendData(event.getActionCommand());
            enterField.setText("");

        }
    });

    add(enterField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    displayArea = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(displayArea));
    setSize(300, 150);
    setLocation(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(50499, 100);
                displayMessage("Listening on Port: "
                        + server.getLocalPort() + "\n");
                for (;;) {
                    Socket nextClient = server.accept();
                    displayMessage("Client Connected");
                    new ClientThread(nextClient).start();
                    nextClient = null;
                }
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void closeConnection() {
    displayMessage("\nTerminating connection\n");
    setTextFieldEditable(false);
    try {
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void displayMessage(final String string) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            displayArea.append(string);
        }
    });
}

private void setTextFieldEditable(final boolean editable) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            enterField.setEditable(editable);

        }

    });

}

private void sendData(String message) {
    try {
        output.writeObject("SERVER>>> " + message);
        output.flush();
        displayMessage("\nSERVER>>> " + message);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        displayArea.append("\nError Writing Object");
    }
}

private class ClientThread extends Thread {

    public ClientThread(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        try {
            connection = socket;
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            displayMessage("Got I/O Stream\n");
            displayMessage("Connection " + counter + " received from: "
                    + 
                            connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            counter++;
            String message = "Connection Sucessful";
            sendData(message);
            setTextFieldEditable(true);
            do {

                message = (String) input.readObject();
                displayMessage("\n" + message);
            } while (!message.endsWith(">>> TERMINATE"));

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
            displayMessage("\nUnknown object type recieved");

        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the connection stuff inside the `ClientThread` constructor. Therefore the `new ClientThread(...)` never returns until you send a `TERMINATE`command. Put the logic inside the `run()` method.

```
private class ClientThread extends Thread {
  private Socket socket;

  // The queue, thread-safe for good measure
  private Queue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

  public ClientThread(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public void send(String message) {
    if (message != null) {
      this.sendQueue.add(message);
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      connection = socket;
      output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      output.flush();
      input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      displayMessage("Got I/O Stream\n");
      displayMessage("Connection " + counter + " received from: " 
          + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
      counter++;
      String message = "Connection Sucessful";
      sendData(message);
      setTextFieldEditable(true);
      do {
        // Purge the queue and send all messages.
        while ((String msg = queue.poll()) != null) {
          sendData(msg);
        }
        message = (String) input.readObject();
        displayMessage("\n" + message);
      } while (!message.endsWith(">>> TERMINATE"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
      displayMessage("\nUnknown object type recieved");
    } finally {
      closeConnection();
    }
  }
}
```

Tipically, you'll send messages to the connection from other threads:

```
ClientThread client = new ClientThread(newClient);
client.start();
client.send("Hi there");
```

Personally, I would have used a non-blocking (NIO) networking library such as [Netty](http://netty.io/) or [Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) to implement this sort of stuff. There's some learning to do to use them but I think its worth it. Non-blocking means that you don't dedicate a separate thread for each connection but rather you're notified when something is received in the socket.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Now I'm working on having the server send messages to both clients that are connected, right now it is only sending one to the latest client that connected. Would that involved creating another thread?

Comment: I see two ways of sending global messages: first you can have a queue of outgoing messages in `ClientThread` and, before you block the thread for input (the `input.readObject()` line), check if the queue is empty and, if it isn't, send all messages it contains and empty it. This has the problem that the thread blocks when waiting for an incoming message, and therefore you could have messages in the outgoing queue not sent because to unblock you need to receive something. The other solution is keep a list of opened sockets and have a new thread go one by one and send the message to all.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to think this through. The queue is implemented on the Client class. And item is added when the message is passed into the 'input.readObject()'. Why would there be messages I'm receiving that need to be outputted again? Could you explain the process of using the queue a little more?

Comment: No, the queue is for outgoing messages, not incoming messages. When you want to send something to a client, you put it in the queue. the `ClientThread`, before doing the `input.readObject()` first checks if there is something in queue and sends its contents using the output stream. Then it does the `readObject()`. The queue's purpose is holding outgoing messages while the client thread is blocked.

Comment: Ok I think I'm going to implement a queue and also a list of clients. First for the queue I would add the message to the queue every time before the `sendData()` method is called, not in the `sendData()` method correct? If the message sends then I would pull the queue in the `sendData()` method. Before the `input.readObject()` I would peek the queue, and if that is null then run the `sendData()` method, if not null then run the `sendData()` method to flush the output?

Comment: I modified the post to demonstrate how to implement the queue, anyway it is simple enough

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide implementation of `run` method for `Thread` Class.

Put processing logic of ClientThread inside `run` method

To keep your code modularised and more manageable make your `ClientThread` class public and share only necessary resources between those thread.

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {  //make class public
  private Socket socket;
// define all other references 
ObjectOutputStream output = null;
//...

  public ClientThread(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      connection = socket;
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        displayMessage("Got I/O Stream\n");
        displayMessage("Connection " + counter + " received from: "
                + 
                        connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        counter++;
        String message = "Connection Sucessful";
        sendData(message);
        setTextFieldEditable(true);
        do {

            message = (String) input.readObject();
            displayMessage("\n" + message);
        } while (!message.endsWith(">>> TERMINATE"));

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
        displayMessage("\nUnknown object type recieved");

    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }

}
}}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Now I'm working on having the server send messages to both clients that are connected, right now it is only sending one to the latest client that connected. Would that involved creating another thread?